# Discard subsequent rules not working in Cart Price Rules

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

I am using Magento 2.3.4. is creating rules:

- Rule 1 : Buy max IDR 900,000 get a 10% discount on your cart
- Rule 2 : Buy min IDR 900,000 - max IDR 3,000,000 get 20% discount on your cart

the condition is :

*if the customer has ordered and gets a 20% discount, then the customer orders again with the conditions for a 10% discount, then the customer will not get another 10% discount*

I've used the '**Discard subsequent rules**' feature but it doesn't seem to work

The following is a display of condition settings and actions for each rule :

[image: Rule 1]

Rule 1

[image: Rule 2]

Rule 2

[image: 10% Off]

The first purchase gets 10% off

[image: 20% Off]

Second spend gets 20% off

The second purchase should not have gotten a 20% discount because the first purchase had already received a 10% discount. So customers only get 1 discount.

Is there anything wrong with my setting conditions and action rules?

Answer (score 0):

your conditions are valid with respect to the cart amounts' thresholds and it's a valid point that you enabled *'Discard subsequent rules'*. However, **your conditions don't mention anything about a previous purchase**.

There isn't any Magento out-of-the-box option to include that since you also have the possibility to apply the rule to guest users, which you can't track from an order history point of view (by default means, that is).

So, what I suggest is to keep the rules' conditions as they are in Magento and **switch them to use coupons which can be used only once**.

Then you could check if it's possible for you (or your client) to distribute the coupon codes to customers or maybe you could implement a mechanism where emails are sent to customers with a unique coupon code they can use if they made purchases over a specific threshold.